# Update Jquery to work with every input button

Tags: jquery, button, input, multiple-instances

I'm using the following code and with a single input button it works fine.

```
<input type="button" id="copy_button" data-clipboard-text="Copy Me!" Value="Click ME">


<script src="js/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
<script>
var clip = new ZeroClipboard( document.getElementById("copy_button"), {
  moviePath: "js/ZeroClipboard.swf"
} );

clip.on( 'complete', function(client, args) {
var $message = $('<div class="message">DONE</div>').hide();
var $messageCont = $('<div class="message_cont" />').append($message).prependTo('body');
$messageCont.css({
   "left" : $(this).offset().left,
   "top" : $(this).offset().top
}).find("div.message").fadeIn(200).delay(1500).fadeOut(function() {
        });
   } );
</script>
```

However I'd ideally like it to work with multiple input buttons and copy the value associated with the correct button.

What do   need to do to make this work ? The final page could have 50+ buttons, so I'm hoping I don't have to specify each button individually.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give a class to all your button and call class seletor

```
var clip = new ZeroClipboard( $(".cpbutton"), {..
```

or

get all input type button

```
var clip = new ZeroClipboard( $("input[type='button']"), {
```